# Remove building names in OpenStreetMap using Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm using leaflet and I used OSM Tile Layer for my map. I want to remove the building names for a specific area (my school) because I'll be adding popup markers instead. I don't want to directly remove the building names in OSM since other users may use it. I found out Mapbox Studio for editing maps but the problem is they're updating their map once a week (I need to make changes in OSM and it will appear instantly in my map).

My question is how can I remove building names of a specific area without removing the data in OSM?

Comment: Since a tile layer is a picture of a map there is no way to do this with out vandalising the underlying OSM dataset, or hosting your own local dataserver.

Comment: @IanTurton that's also what I thought